# Netty client not receving message from fast server

Tags: tcp, netty, broadcast

I have a sample server/client application using netty for tcp communication between them.

The problem I am facing is when Server pushes messages to the connected client at a slower pace, client receives all the messages, but when there is no delay between data push from server, client does not receive all the messages. Here is my sample server code

```
public class NettyServer {
public NettyServer() throws InterruptedException {
    final ClientChannelHolder clientChannelHolder = new ClientChannelHolder();
    NioEventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(group).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(9000)).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientChannelHandler(clientChannelHolder));
        }
    });
    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener(){
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Server bound ");
        }
    });
    synchronized (clientChannelHolder) {
        // wait for client to be conncted
        clientChannelHolder.wait();
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++) {
        // loop to broadcast to all connected clients
        clientChannelHolder.broadCast(i);
        //Thread.sleep(1000); if I add this sleep client works fine and gets all messages
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    NettyServer nettyServer = new NettyServer();
}

// collection for all connected clients.
public static class ClientChannelHolder {
    private List<Channel> clientChannels = new LinkedList<>();

    private synchronized void addClientChannel(Channel socketChannel) {
        // notify the cleint is connected
        notify();
        clientChannels.add(socketChannel);
    }

    private synchronized void removeClientChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        clientChannels.remove(socketChannel);
    }

    public void broadCast(int msgId) {
        for (Channel channel : clientChannels) {
            byte[] bytes = ("server msg " + msgId).getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(bytes.length);
            ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer();
            byteBuf.writeByte((byte)1);
            byteBuf.writeInt(1);
            byteBuf.writeInt(bytes.length);
            byteBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
            channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf).addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(Future<? super Void> future) throws Exception {
                    if (future.isSuccess()) {
                        System.out.println("Write successfull");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


public static class ClientChannelHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    private final ClientChannelHolder clientChannelHolder;

    public ClientChannelHandler(ClientChannelHolder clientChannelHolder) {
        this.clientChannelHolder = clientChannelHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        clientChannelHolder.addClientChannel(ctx.channel());
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        super.channelActive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }


    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        in.markReaderIndex();
        byte version = in.readByte();
        int msgType = in.readInt();
        int msgLength = in.readInt();
        byte[] msgArray = new byte[msgLength];
        if (in.readableBytes() < msgLength) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        in.readBytes(msgArray, 0, msgLength);
        System.out.println(
                "Server received: " + new String(msgArray, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}
}
```

If I remove the comment before the sleep statement, client gets all the messages. But With this commented sleep, client looses many messages in between, even though the server prints "Write successfull"

Here is my cleint side code:
    public class NettyClient {

```
public NettyClient(final int clientId , NioEventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup, final ClientChannelHolder clientChannelHolder)

        throws InterruptedException {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000))
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    clientChannelHolder.addClientChannel(ch);
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientChannelHandler(clientId));
                }
            });
    bootstrap.connect().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(clientId +  "Client connected");
        }
    });
}

public static class ClientChannelHolder {
    private List<Channel> clientChannels = new LinkedList<>();

    private synchronized void addClientChannel(Channel socketChannel) {
        clientChannels.add(socketChannel);
    }

    private synchronized void removeClientChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        clientChannels.remove(socketChannel);
    }

    public void broadCast(int msgId) {
        for (Channel channel : clientChannels) {
            byte[] bytes = ("cleint msg" + msgId).getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.buffer();
            byteBuf.writeByte(1);
            byteBuf.writeInt(1);
            byteBuf.writeInt(bytes.length);
            byteBuf.writeBytes(bytes);
            channel.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
        }
    }
}

public static class ClientChannelHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private int clientId = 1;

    public ClientChannelHandler(int clientId){
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        in.markReaderIndex();
        byte version = in.readByte();
        int msgType = in.readInt();
        int msgLength = in.readInt();
        System.out.println(msgLength);
        byte[] msgArray = new byte[msgLength];
        if (in.readableBytes() < msgLength) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        in.readBytes(msgArray, 0, msgLength);
        System.out.println(clientId +
                " Client received: " + new String(msgArray, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    NioEventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ClientChannelHolder clientChannelHolder = new ClientChannelHolder();
    NettyClient nettyClient = new NettyClient(1, group, clientChannelHolder);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You wrote your client handler assuming to extend `ByteToMessageDecoder`, but the extended `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` instead.

In Netty, there are different approaches to read incoming data, while this is confusing, it is so because the way TCP is written, namely stream based. This means that while TCP guarantees that all data enters your application in order, it does not guarantee any packet size, nor the size of incoming packets.

With your code, you extend from the simplest class, namely `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`. This means that your program gets all incoming data as TCP provides it to your program. While this usually (but not always, think of packet loss) goes well for data send send 1 second apart, it breaks down as packets are send more frequently.

To see why this goes wrong, image a single `ByteBuf` containing 2 of your protocol specific packets, if your code is executed, then basicly only the first one is read.

## Solving the problem

By looking at your original client code, it looks like it was written for extending a `ByteToMessageDecoder` instead of a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`, as seen by the usage of `markReaderIndex` and `resetReaderIndex`, so changing the parent class (and the overridden method) is the first step.

```
public class ClientChannelHandler extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) { 
        in.markReaderIndex();
        byte version = in.readByte();
        int msgType = in.readInt();
        int msgLength = in.readInt();
        System.out.println(msgLength);
        byte[] msgArray = new byte[msgLength];
        if (in.readableBytes() < msgLength) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        in.readBytes(msgArray, 0, msgLength);
        System.out.println(clientId +
            " Client received: " + new String(msgArray, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

This, however isn't the final solution, as there are 2 problems to solve:

- `ByteToMessageDecoder` expects a output, so it knows when a packet is read.
- Image your code gets a packet of the length of 3 bytes, your `readInt` call will give an error.

### Solving the output problem

For the first problem, we are going to tackle the problem by splitting up the handler between printing and decoding.

```
public class ClientChannelDecoderHandler extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) { 
        in.markReaderIndex();
        byte version = in.readByte();
        int msgType = in.readInt();
        int msgLength = in.readInt();
        System.out.println(msgLength);
        byte[] msgArray = new byte[msgLength];
        if (in.readableBytes() < msgLength) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        in.readBytes(msgArray, 0, msgLength);
        out.add(clientId +
            " Client received: " + new String(msgArray, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}
public static class ClientChannelPrinterHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println((String)msg);
    }
}

// When making your bootstrap netty object:
 .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                clientChannelHolder.addClientChannel(ch);
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientChannelDecodeHandler(clientId));
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientChannelPrintingHandler(clientId));
            }
        });
```

### Solving the message lower than 3 problem

Solving the problem is easy compared to the previous problem. We just need to return when our message is too small.

```
public class ClientChannelDecoderHandler extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {
        if (in.readableBytes() < 1 + 4 + 4) { // byte + int + int
            return;
        }
        in.markReaderIndex();
        ....
```